# dfx cannister in my local Dapp file fails saying file not found

Tags: linux, blockchain, decentralized-applications

```
import Debug "mo:base/Debug";

actor DBank{
  var currentValue = 300;
  currentValue := 100;

  Debug.print("Hello");
}
```

Running the command `dfx start`:

```
Running dfx start for version 0.12.1
Using the default definition for the 'local' shared network because /home/karthik/.config/dfx/networks.json does not exist.
Dashboard: http://localhost:40021/_/dashboard
```

Also the `dfx deploy` command reports:

```
Error: Failed while trying to deploy canisters.
Caused by: Failed while trying to deploy canisters.
  Cannot find dfx configuration file in the current working directory. Did you forget to create one?
```

Answer (score 3):

for the **dfx start** section:

```
DFX_VERSION=0.9.3 sh -ci "$(curl -fsSL https://sdk.dfinity.org/install.sh)"
```

i strongly recommend that you use the above version, not the latest updated versions because there are some instability between the latest version. Then use the `dfx start --clean` so that it would clear all the previously stored canisters

For the **dfx Deploy** section:
you need to 'cd' into your working project root in other to deploy canisters.
Something like: `ic-project/dbank`

Answer (score 0):

The bug is still there even in 0.16.0, it is advised from their [official forum](https://forum.dfinity.org/t/major-bug-in-dfx-0-16-0-with-azle/26957/5) to upgrade to the latest --version 0.17.0, or simply run the below command:

```
DFX_VERSION=0.17.0-beta.0 sh -ci "$(curl -fsSL https://internetcomputer.org/install.sh)"
```